# Using IF function in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Ive tried to find the OLDEST FEMALE from csv dataset, but I dont know how. Im pretty new to Python and Pandas. I clearly dont know how to use if function here.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("people.csv", usecols=['gender', 'age'])
```

I tried to use something like this

```
print(df[df["gender"].isin(["F"])].df.age.max())
```

or like this

```
if df[df["gender"].all(["F"])] :
print(df.age.max())
```

even tried this

```
print(df.loc[df['gender'] == 'F'].max())
```

but this was before I found the oldest 'M' is the same age as the oldest 'F'

but still cant figure out how to find the oldest female

EDIT : I have to find the oldest female from imported dataset, not to create one. Thank you.

EDIT 2 : Sorry for bothering, I just found out, that the oldest M in my csv have the same age as the oldest F in my csv. This is embarassing

Comment: Adding few rows from your csv would help answer the question better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need an if statement in this context. See below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': ['M', 'F', 'F','F','M'],
      'age': [99,12,45,98,23]})

# Result
print(df[df['gender'] == 'F']['age'].max())
```

This should give you what you are looking for. Also, don't forget to indent the next line after an if statement.

Comment: I recommend against using chained indexing, noted by '][' these two characters in a pandas statement back to back.   Instead, do this `df.loc[df['gender'] == 'F', 'age'].max()`

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':['F', 'M', 'F', 'M','F', 'M'],'age': [12, 33, 43, 22, 18, 16]})

oldest_female = df.loc[df['gender'] == 'F'].max()

print(oldest_female['age'])
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. This part selects females only `df.loc[df['gender'] == 'F']`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. First group by `gender` and get max values. Then get the `age` from it for Females.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['F',20],['F',30], ['M',20]], columns=['gender', 'age'])

df = df.groupby('gender').max().reset_index()
print(df[df['gender'] == 'F'].iloc[0]['age'])
```

Output is `30` in this example

Comment: @helperman200: Since the input data was not provided, I have created a sample data, with the column names as specified in the question. Hence ideally this should work. If you are having issues with this, then please provide sample data from your csv. It would help to answer the question better.

Answer (score 2):

To find the row of the oldest female in the data set you can filter your dataframe to only females, the use idxmax to find the index:

```
df.loc[df.query('gender == "F"')['age'].idxmax()]
```

This will return the first row in your dataset with a max age of gender 'F'.